# Problems calling another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have to use 2 classes to complete a sort of game,

"Units" are the soldiers that fight in our fictitious war. Units will be defined by a class in python called Unit. For Nick Wars, our units will have the following properties:

Team - A string indicating which team the unit belongs to. This will always either be "Red" or "Blue". Must be initialized.
HP - hitpoints / health / energy / pep. The amount of damage a unit can sustain before being killed. Units can not regain or recover HP. Must be initialized.
ATT - attack / strength. The amount of damage a unit can do in a single hit. Must be initialized.
attack_timeout - The amount of time that must pass between attacks, measured in tick's (see methods below). Must be initialized.
isDead - True if this unit is dead, False if it is living. Initializes to False.
Methods:

tick(self, opponents) - each time tick is called, we simulate one unit of time passing inside the game scenario. Any "automatic" behaviours of a unit are defined here (so, we are in essence programming the unit AI). The argument opponents is a list of all units which are valid attack targets. The following behaviours must be created if isDead is False. A dead unit performs none of these behaviours and immediately returns the integer value 0.
If the list of opponents has any living units, this unit attacks the unit with the lowest HP (see the attack method). In this case, this method returns the integer value 0. If multiple units have the same HP, go with the first unit with that HP in the list of opposing units.
If the list of opponents is empty or contains no living units, return this unit's attack value. This will be used later to calculate damage to the enemy's base.
The above two actions can only occur if it has been the specified number of ticks since the last attack by this unit. How to keep try of this is left as an exercise to the reader.
attack(self, other) - Called when this unit (self) attacks a defending unit (other). The defending unit has it's HP reduced by this unit's attack value. If this reduces the defending unit's HP to or past zero, set isDead to True.

I've completed this part and it looks like this

```
class Unit:

def __init__(self,Team,HP,ATT,attack_timeout,isDead = False):
    self.Team = Team
    self.HP = HP
    self.ATT = ATT
    self.attack_timeout = attack_timeout
    self.isDead = isDead
    self.lastuse = attack_timeout
    
def attack(self,other):
    self.lastuse = 0
    other.HP -= self.ATT
    if other.HP <= 0:
        other.isDead = True

def tick(self,opponents):
    
    if self.isDead == True:
        return 0
    
    else:
        
        healths = []
        lowest = None
        
        if not opponents:
            self.lastuse = 0
            return self.ATT
        
        
            
        if self.lastuse == self.attack_timeout:
            
            for i in opponents:
                healths.append(i.HP)
            
            if sum(healths)<=0:
                self.lastuse = 0
                return self.ATT
            
            else:
                for i in opponents:
                    if lowest == None or i.HP < lowest:
                        lowest = i.HP
                for j in opponents:
                    if j.HP == lowest:
                        break

                Unit.attack(self,j)
                return (0)


        self.lastuse += 1
        return 0
```

the second part that is giving me difficulty is using this class in an army class given below

Since a lot of code will be reused between the two opposing armies, it makes sense to encapsulate them as their own class.

Define an Army class with the following properties and methods:

Properties:

Team - A string indicating which team the unit belongs to. This will always either be "Red" or "Blue". Must be initialized.
BaseHP - The amount of health the army's base has remaining. Initializes to 1000
GoldRate - The number of gold the army gains per tick. Initializes to 10.
Gold - The amount of gold the team has for buying units and increasing GoldRate. Initializes to 0.
Roster - A list of dictionaries specifying the properties of the units available for purchase. Must be initialized.
Price - The amount of gold the unit costs
HP - amount of health the unit starts with
ATT - attack power of the unit
attack_timeout - number of time the unit must wait between attacks.
Units - A list of Unit objects which currently exist.
Methods:

tick(self,opponents) - Aside from self, takes a list of the other team's units opponents. Invokes the tick methods of every unit in the list of Units, and passes each the list of opponents. The return values of each Unit's tick method indicate the amount of damage done to the opponent's base. Compute the sum of these return values and return that sum from this tick method. In addition, the team's Gold value is increased by the value of GoldRate.
BuryDead(self) - Removes from the list of Units all Units for which isDead is True.
BuyGoldRate(self) - If the team has more than 250 gold, reduces the team's gold by 250 and adds 2 to GoldRate.
BuyUnit(self, x) - x is an integer indicating the index of the unit in the roster is to be purchased. If the team has an amount of gold greater than or equal to the Price value of the unit specified by x, a new Unit is initialized with the properties specified in the roster entry, and is added to the Units list. If the specified roster item doesn't exist, raise a NoSuchUnitError exception. If there is not enough gold to purchase the unit, create a TooPoorError exception.

I tried doing this

```
class TooPoorError (Exception):
     pass

class NoSuchUnitError (Exception):
     pass

class Army(Unit):

     def __init__ (self,Team,Roster,BaseHP = 1000,GoldRate = 10,Gold = 0):
         self.Team = Team
         self.BaseHP = BaseHP
         self.GoldRate = GoldRate
         self.Gold = Gold
         self.Roster = Roster
         self.Units = []
    
    def tick (self,opponents):
         self.Gold += self.GoldRate  
         for i in self.Units:
             return (Unit.tick(i,opponents))       
        
    def BuryDead(self):
         pass
            
        
    def BuyGoldRate(self):
         if self.Gold>=250:
             self.GoldRate += 2
              self.Gold-= 250

    def BuyUnit(self, x):
             if self.Gold>=self.Roster[x]["Price"]:
                 self.Gold -= self.Roster[x]["Price"]
                 self.Units.append(Unit(self,self.Roster[x]["HP"],self.Roster[x]["ATT"],self.Roster[x]["attack_timeout"]) )
            
             if self.Gold<self.Roster[x]["Price"]:
                 raise TooPoorError
```

I'm having trouble using my previous class in order to run the tick function and keep getting a return of 0

the test case is below:

```
#Visible test

RedArmy  = Army('Red',  [{'Price': 20, 'HP': 100, 'ATT': 7, 'attack_timeout': 3},
                         {'Price': 15, 'HP':  70, 'ATT': 5, 'attack_timeout': 2}])

BlueArmy = Army('Blue', [{'Price': 13, 'HP':  60, 'ATT': 4, 'attack_timeout': 1},
                         {'Price': 16, 'HP':  80, 'ATT': 6, 'attack_timeout': 3}])

# Collecting gold

for i in range(30):
    RedArmy.tick([])
    BlueArmy.tick([])

RedArmy.BuyGoldRate()
BlueArmy.BuyGoldRate()

for i in range(5):
    RedArmy.tick([])
    BlueArmy.tick([])

    
# Training the army

RedArmy.BuyUnit(0)
RedArmy.BuyUnit(0)
RedArmy.BuyUnit(1)

BlueArmy.BuyUnit(1)
BlueArmy.BuyUnit(1)
BlueArmy.BuyUnit(1)
BlueArmy.BuyUnit(0)

print('Gold calculation for Blue: --------', BlueArmy.Gold == 49)
print('Gold calculation for Red: ---------', RedArmy.Gold == 55)

# Fight
    
BlueDamage = 0
RedDamage  = 0

BlueUnits_HP = []
BlueUnits_Dead = []

RedUnits_HP = []
RedUnits_Dead = []

for i in range(80):
    BlueDamage += RedArmy.tick(BlueArmy.Units)
    RedDamage  += BlueArmy.tick(RedArmy.Units)
    
for u in BlueArmy.Units:
    BlueUnits_HP += [u.HP]
    BlueUnits_Dead += [u.isDead]

for u in RedArmy.Units:
    RedUnits_HP  += [u.HP]
    RedUnits_Dead += [u.isDead]

print('Damage calcultion for Blue: -------', BlueDamage == 0)
print('Damage calcultion for Red: --------', RedDamage == 42)
print('Blue units HP: --------------------', BlueUnits_HP == [-4, 31, 80, -4] or BlueUnits_HP == [0, 31, 80, 0])
print('Blue units status: ----------------', BlueUnits_Dead == [True, False, False, True])
print('Red units HP: ---------------------', RedUnits_HP == [-4, -2, 0] or RedUnits_HP == [0, 0, 0])
print('Red units status: -----------------', RedUnits_Dead == [True, True, True])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was pretty fun code to play around with!
I had to make a few changes to get it to work, partly to understand what was happening and make the code a bit more pythonic. I made some assumptions about the intended purpose of various methods/how you wanted the attack priorities to work, but I'll explain everything and try justify it all.

**General**
Throughout I've switched from CamelCase to snake_case for variable names, and have passed the code through a linter to bring it in line with the Python PEP 8 style guide.

Added the `TooPoorError`

```py
class NoSuchUnitError(Exception):
    pass


class TooPoorError(Exception):
    pass
```

**Army**

Added guard clauses to raise exceptions when buying units.
Changed how tick worked a little - now you can call it as `army.tick()` to just advance gold, or pass in another army to battle them. The way you had called the tick was a bit weird, so I'm not sure if that was perhaps what was giving you a return of 0? You can just loop over the units in `army.units` and for each `unit`, call the `tick` method against the opponent. I used a list comprehension to do this loop and sum the output damage. I think you may have been encountering some issues because you were returning the output of the first units 'tick', and killing the loop.

You were also inheriting from Unit - I wouldn't say an Army is-a Unit, instead that an Army has-a Unit.

```py
class Army:

    def __init__(self, team, roster, hp=1000, gold_rate=10, gold=0):
        self.team = team
        self.hp = hp
        self.gold_rate = gold_rate
        self.gold = gold
        self.roster = roster
        self.units = []

    def tick(self, opponents=None):
        self.gold += self.gold_rate

        if opponents is not None:
            return sum([unit.tick(opponents) for unit in self.units])

    def buy_gold_rate(self):
        if self.gold >= 250:
            self.gold_rate += 2
            self.gold -= 250

    def buy_unit(self, x):
        if self.gold < self.roster[x]["Price"]:
            raise TooPoorError

        if x > len(self.roster):
            raise NoSuchUnitError

        self.gold -= self.roster[x]["Price"]
        self.units.append(Unit(self.roster[x]["HP"], self.roster[x]["ATT"],
                               self.roster[x]["attack_timeout"]))
```

**Unit**

Removed the team passed in as a keyword to clear things up a bit, as it wasn't used. Removed the isDead argument (would you ever make a new Unit that starts dead?).

Guard clauses are a nice way to minimise the amount of indentation used, and I put a couple in the `tick` method. I also added a property that helps make the tracking of whether the unit is on cooldown a bit simpler.

```py
class Unit:
    def __init__(self, hp, attack_strength, attack_timeout):
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack_strength = attack_strength
        self.attack_timeout = attack_timeout
        self._last_use = attack_timeout

        self.is_dead = False

    def attack(self, other):
        self.lastuse = 0
        other.hp -= self.attack_strength
        if other.hp <= 0:
            other.hp = 0
            other.is_dead = True

    def tick(self, opponent):
        # 
        if self.is_dead:
            return 0

        if self.on_cooldown:
            self._last_use += 1
            return 0

        # Find out if any opposing units are alive
        if all([unit.is_dead for unit in opponent.units]):
            self._last_use = 0
            return self.attack_strength
        else:
            lowest_hp = 1e10
            for unit in opponent.units:
                if unit.hp < lowest_hp and not unit.is_dead:
                    lowest = unit
                    lowest_hp = unit.hp

            self.attack(lowest)

        self._last_use = 0
        return 0

    @property
    def on_cooldown(self):
        if self._last_use != self.attack_timeout:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Here are the updated tests:

```py
red_army = Army('Red',  [{'Price': 20, 'HP': 100, 'ATT': 7, 'attack_timeout': 3},
                         {'Price': 15, 'HP':  70, 'ATT': 5, 'attack_timeout': 2}])

blue_army = Army('Blue', [{'Price': 13, 'HP':  60, 'ATT': 4, 'attack_timeout': 1},
                          {'Price': 16, 'HP':  80, 'ATT': 6, 'attack_timeout': 3}])

# Collecting gold
for _ in range(30):
    red_army.tick()
    blue_army.tick()

red_army.buy_gold_rate()
blue_army.buy_gold_rate()

for _ in range(5):
    red_army.tick()
    blue_army.tick()

# Training the army
red_army.buy_unit(0)
red_army.buy_unit(0)
red_army.buy_unit(1)

blue_army.buy_unit(1)
blue_army.buy_unit(1)
blue_army.buy_unit(1)
blue_army.buy_unit(0)

print('Gold calculation for Blue: --------', blue_army.gold == 49)

print('Gold calculation for Red: ---------', red_army.gold == 55)

# Fight
blue_damage = 0
red_damage = 0

for i in range(80):
    blue_damage += red_army.tick(blue_army)
    red_damage += blue_army.tick(red_army)

blue_units_hp = [unit.hp for unit in blue_army.units]
blue_units_dead = [unit.is_dead for unit in blue_army.units]

red_units_hp = [unit.hp for unit in red_army.units]
red_units_dead = [unit.is_dead for unit in red_army.units]

print('Damage calculation for Blue: ---', blue_damage == 0)
print('Damage calculation for Red: ----', red_damage == 42)
print('Blue units HP: -----------------', blue_units_hp == [0, 31, 80, 0])
print('Blue units status: -------------', blue_units_dead == [True, False, False, True])
print('Red units HP: ------------------', red_units_hp == [0, 0, 0])
print('Red units status: --------------', red_units_dead == [True, True, True])
```